# Transformar esa query sql a Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo esta linea SQL

```
select id_comuna ,count(id_comuna) 
from estacionamiento 
group by id_comuna 
having count(id_comuna)>1 
ORDER BY `count(id_comuna)` DESC LIMIT 6
```

Y me muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo pasar esta query a Laravel Eloquent ORM?

Esto es lo que tengo por ahora

```
public function getComunasDestacadasAttribute()
{
    $comunas = DB::table('estacionamiento')
        ->select('id_comuna')
        ->count('id_comuna')
        ->groupBy('id_comuna')
        ->orderBy('id_comuna', 'DESC')
        ->limit(6);
    return $comunas;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentarlo de esta forma:

- No hay necesidad de usar el facade DB, en su lugar trabaja con el modelo referido a la tabla `estacionamiento`
- Con el método `selectRaw()` toma la primer columna deseada y pasa una sentencia SQL de agregación para obtener el conteo de la segunda
- A la segunda columna generada por la función de agregación dale un alias (*mismo que usaremos después*)
- Usamos el método `having` para filtrar por el resultado de la columna calculada y que usaremos a través de su alias
- Hacemos un ordenamiento evitando usar la función de agregación nuevamente y solo tomar en su lugar por su alias la columna generada
- Usamos el método `take()`

Quedando así:

```
Estacionamiento::selectRaw("id_comuna, COUNT(id_comuna) AS Total")
                            ->groupBy('id_comuna')
                            ->having('Total', '>', 1)
                            ->orderBy('Total', 'DESC')
                            ->take(6)
                            ->get();
```

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [método take y having](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)
- [Método selectRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods)